# What are requirements for mobile internet dongle working on Raspbery Pi?

Tags: usb, internet, gsm

I have mobile internet dongle `ZTE MF833R` with unlocked SIM card and it is working without any configuration if I plug it into Mac or Linux.

If I plug it into Raspi I have

```
# cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
...
# cat /proc/cpuinfo
...
Hardware        : BCM2835
Revision        : a22082

# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 020: ID 19d2:1405 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
...
```

Unfortunately, `ifconfig` doesn't show any new devices. This Raspi is highly tuned. Where sould I check to ensure mobile USB dongle is connecting to internet?

---

I see device is appearing in

```
# ip link
...
4: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 34:4b:50:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

why isn't it `usb0` or something? Does this mean I need to specify this iface in `/etc/network/interfaces`?

If I specify there

```
auto eth1
allow-hotplug eth1

iface eth1 inet dhcp
metric 1
```

I can up interface with `ifup`. Is it convenient way?

Comment: Is Jessie even supported any more?  Have you tried a more modern version?

Answer (score 1):

Start by finding out what driver your device gets (look into `dmesg` logs for a start). Those dongles often present themselves as flash disks containing windows drivers, and special trickery is required to get them recognized as modem devices.

If your dongle is recognized as a modem, look for a `wvdial` configuration for your specific model and see if `sudo wvdial` gets you connected.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use wvdial.

Most USB 4G dongles contain multiple logical devices. You need usb_modeswitch to make Linux recognize the modem and NetworkManager to manage the connection.

The guide is here: https://whiteboxcellphone.com/psd/usb4g-linux.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I'm not sure what additional supporting information you would like. Everything is in the provided link.